# Spring @Autowired with interfaces

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Does spring @Autowired annotation auto-wires an intrerface which does not have its implementation class? If Yes how?

e.g

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    
}
```

```
@RestController
public class UserJpaResource {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository service;
```

Comment: Yes it does autowire it because it does have an implementation, though the implementation is being generated

Comment: Do you mean it auto-generates the implementation class itself and then Autowires that bean?

Comment: it generate implementation for `UserRepository` under Spring JPA hood

Answer (score 2):

Spring Data scans for Interfaces which extends from, as an example JpaRepository, and creates a default Implementation for you under the hood.

Further informations:

[Spring-Data-Repositorys](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories)

Comment: Note that (even if correct) the linked reference is severely outdated (from 2013). More current documentation can be found at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/2.7.6/reference/html/#repositories